# How to forward slots, with fallback slots in Svelte components

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I'm working on a Dropdown component. And I want to create a Select component based on Dropdown.svelte.

I want the Select component to use the fallbacks slots of Dropdown component.

I created this simple example, a `Card` component with two slots, each with a fallback content, to reproduce the issue:

```html
<!-- Card.svelte -->
<script>
    export let name = '';
    export let phone = '';
</script>

<div>
    This is a card
    <slot name='name'>
        <div>hello {name}</div>
    </slot>

    <slot name='phone' {phone}>
        <div>call me at {phone}</div>
    </slot>
</div>
```

I want to create a `AnonCard` component based on this `Card` component. I should be able to customize it specifying custom slots, and if not specified I want it to use the `Card.svelte` fallback.

this is AnonCard.svelte

```html
<!-- AnonCard.svelte -->
<script>
    import Card from './Card.svelte'
</script>

<Card name="Anonymous" phone="no phone">

    <slot name="name" slot="name" />

    <slot name="phone" slot="phone" />
</Card>
```

If I customize the `name` and `phone` slots, it works ok, but If I leave them empty the slot fallbacks from Card.svelte are NOT used.

See a screenshots:

[image]

Any idea how to achieve it?

> note: see the sample [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/97a5e695ebb24f8493dd50d54f128370?version=4.2.3)

Comment: It would be possible [in Svelte 5](https://svelte-5-preview.vercel.app/#H4sIAAAAAAAACq1SwWqEMBD9lWlacBdEL3uyWrr01kMv7a32IBoxoElIsgtL8N-bjMpGdhEKhRxmhvfezLyJJS3rqSbZtyW8GijJyFFKEhNzkT7RZ9ob6nItTqr2lVzXiknzUvLSsEEKZeCtUg20SgwQJalPkokWBZgjF3yFWwpXbJ5epXmOYD9SUZJ30fGSgOwE9-nhcHBZOuE6tUSLIo5mHzVnUlKDGp9TvNuPHwIL0FFFH2w6g8Y1BRutOFhBEnDKjAtW5DwNm98bCnPn4yAa1jLakMyoEx3jq-0z8D-9rwXXBiwkSSKVkBpGKOAJw93-ectxP81lECcd2M5nG1zJLoqj22trq79stEyL9ykgiuLZ9ikO7hivLrS9VcPOqP7VMQ3uVVC7maZ7szZUxU9QGmTYV0V5Q9Xq9_h4P-bpImkz2msa0jra9wKsB4a4lLUetfQMh7_bdPX_MNluW1d9D860ytmH8NvmU-H2VD_jL-9HLygDBAAA)...

Comment: you mean with the snippets stuff, right?

Comment: Yes, the link should show a working demo.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the svelte5 version, is much straightforward to treat them slots as regular props that can be empty

Comment: just created an issue at svelte repo: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/9452